# sampling in hive into data sets 80% and 20%

Tags: hive

How can I sample the data from Hive table into 2 parts: 80% and 20%. Do I have to sample by bucket 1 to 5 and union 4 out of those 5 for one table or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3):

This is where the multiple output syntax would come in handy. Choose a key which is fairly random, perform an md5 hash, and then take modulo 10.

```
from ( select md5( id) % 10 as bucket_key, * from mytable) sample_set
  insert overwrite table eighty_percent 
    ( select * from sample_set where bucket_key < 8) 
  insert overwrite table twenty_percent
    ( select * from sample_set where bucket_key >= 8 );
```

Comment: You could also just use rand() as the bucket_key to have a guaranteed 80-20 split in case there's no convenient, nicely-distributed 'id' field.

Comment: @Jerome Banks- I need little help to prepare a dynamic query to get the sample data from bucketed hive table.. ie. Using hash value of my search column

Answer (score 0):

If replacement is OK and you don't mind approximately 80% and approximately 20% you can use block sampling.

If replacement is not ok, I think the method you mention is the only approach. If you cluster your source table into 5 buckets you should be able to do this with good performance.